# How to configure splittext nifi or how to split file data in apache nifi?

Tags: text, split, apache-nifi

how to split lines while keeping the first line in each output file. I'm using apache nifi and saw that you can use SplitText so that it considers the first line to be the title

input: "1\nбережливое производство\nканбан\nсокращение потерь"
output: {"id": 1, "value": "бережливое производство"} ...

Comment: Could you please provide what is your expected output based on the input provided

Comment: {"id": 1, "value": "бережливое производство"}, {"id": 1, "value": "канбан"}, {"id": 1, "value": "сокращение потерь"}

Comment: so, you have one id for all other values? could you please edit your question and use formatting to show real content. do you quotes in input?